# ora 27101 shared memory real does not exist when connecting to remote server

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a problem with a remote Oracle database server, it runs in windows and my client runs on linux

if I use sqlplus with the ORACLE_SID it works

```
sqlplus my_user/my_pass@REMOTEDB
```

However if I do the same by using the ORACLE_SID environment variable this error appears:

```
export ORACLE_SID = REMOTEDB
sqlplus my_user/my_pass

ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
```

this is my tnsnames.ora file

```
REMOTEDB =
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.150)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SID = REMOTEDB)
        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    )
)
```

and this is my listener.ora file

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
    (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
    (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome)
    #      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome\bin\oraclr11.dll")
)
(SID_DESC =
 (SID_NAME = REMOTEDB)
 (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome)
  #     (PROGRAM = extproc)
 (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome\bin\oraclr11.dll")
)
)

LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.150)(PORT = 1521))
    )
)
```

I'm really stuck with this, any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORACLE_SID only works for local databases that use the BEQ adapter (implemented with pipes, not network sockets). Use TWO_TASK instead if you want to connect to a remote database. (And don't question the name TWO_TASK, it has historical reasons ;-)

See, for example, http://ora-exp.blogspot.de/2007/06/oraclesid-and-twotask-environment_21.html (it's a bit old but not outdated).